# Scalr resize and crop to size

Tags: image-resizing, resize-crop, imgscalr

I would like to show an image in all sort of placements with different width and height.

I am using a method for crop and resize with Sclar,
But I have 2 problems:

1. The result doesn't look so good in some cases. I think it is because the image in the code is first scaled.
2. I get an exception in other cases. For example:

> Invalid crop bounds: x [32], y [-1], width [64] and height [64] must
>   all be >= 0

What is the best way of resizing a cropping and image to some target width and height?

Here is my current method:

```
  public static BufferedImage resizeAndCropToCenter(BufferedImage image, int width, int height) {
    image = Scalr.resize(image, Scalr.Method.QUALITY, Scalr.Mode.FIT_TO_WIDTH,
        width * 2, height * 2, Scalr.OP_ANTIALIAS);

    int x, y;

    int imageWidth = image.getWidth();
    int imageHeight = image.getHeight();

    if (imageWidth > imageHeight) {
      x = width / 2;
      y = (imageHeight - height) / 2;
    } else {
      x = (imageWidth - width) / 2;
      y = height / 2;
    }


    return Scalr.crop(image, x, y, width, height);
  }
```

Comment: Hi, I am stuck on the same issue. did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

1. In the resize method, you are always doing FIT_TO_WIDTH no matter what the dimensions are.    Perhaps you should do something different depending on whether the image and the desired size are both portrait or landscape format.  What do you aim to achieve here?
2. Instead of

   ```
   y = (imageHeight - height) / 2;
   ```

use

```
y = Math.abs((imageHeight - height) / 2);
```

to make sure y is never negative.  Do the same for x in the else block.